# How to set a specific taxonomy with Rules during feeds import?

Tags: 7, rules, feeds

Using Feeds, Drupal creates automatically a Rule "before saving a content imported by feeds".

In my XML file I've got a unlimited value field that goes into one unlimited value field in my content type and I would like to create a rule that populates another field in my content type with one specific term grabbed from the XML field.

i.e
One item in the XML file has got terms:

**Fruit, Sicily, Oranges**

Another item has got other terms:

**Nut, Sicily, Chestnuts**

From here I need to grab just Fruit or Nuts.

So I've created two Rules:

The first one checks if the field contains the term Fruit.

1. Event: Before Saving a node from xml feed
2. Condition: Data comparision TRUE with term ID of **Fruit**.
3. Action: Here I would like to grab **Fruit**.

The second Rules is similar to the first one, but it checks if it contains **Nut**.

I've tried to set the Action with Set data value -> Target field node:field-type:Taxonomy(Name) -> Set a fixed value. It does not work.

I would like to know how to set the Action. If it's not possible using Rules, how do I achieve this aim?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Rules

1. Before saving a node from xml feeds
2. Data comparision TRUE with rem id **Fruit**
3. Set data value -> node:field-taxonomy-type -> click on "Switch to direct mode input" and it will show the terms for that Vocabulary.